# Laravel The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. Yet i am using PUT method

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to make functionality where user deletes his/her account using laravel and i am getting the error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT."...i dont know what i am doing wrong...

below is my function in UserController

```
public function del()
{
    $user = \User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    Auth::logout();
    if ($user->delete()) {
        return Redirect::route('welcome');
    }
}
```

In blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form method="put" action="wipe">
                @csrf
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Dalete Account</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

My route in web.php looks as follows

```
Route::put('users/wipe', 'UserController@del')->name('users.wipe');
```

I will appreciate any help...thanks in advance

Comment: The `form` element doesn't support `PUT` as a method. Instead you need to use `@method('PUT')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PUT in the form method attribute:
use "post" and the blade directive `@method`

```
<form method="post" action="wipe">
@method('PUT')
```

However to delete a user, maybe the DELETE method is a better option? (implement the same way as the PUT method)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it looks working i just got a different error message "Class "App\Http\Controllers\App\User" not found "

Comment: @Daniel `use App\User` at the top of your controller.

Comment: Thank you once more @Gert B your answer solved my problem entirely